# Fullpage.js choppy scrolling on Android 4.2.1

Tags: android, html, css, webview, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js for an html5/css3/jquery based app for Android 4.2 tablet, that I generate with PhoneGap web service. On PC and emulators everything works smooth and fast, but on tablet itself scrolling between sections is very slow and choppy. Scrolling between slides is a bit better, though not smooth either. I have css3: true in fullpage.js options and I use very light-weight images and elements for the app. Let's say each section loads around 50kb per scroll. I have fixed background for all sections and it stays in place without lags, only loaded per-section content is getting choppy (it looks like it's loading in square patches). 
When I open the same html files in tablet's Chrome browser, everything works smooth as well. So I believe it's Android's default WebView causing this choppiness and issues. Is there any way to make it work smooth with fullpage.js?

Comment: Do you have the same problem when accessing the [demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) from your Android web browser?

Comment: No, it works smoothly in default browser, just like my page on Chrome. But your page doesn't really have any content there, it's just css color and text. My app has two layers of full screen images in each section. 30kb Jpg in the background and  1kb svg on top. It's not that big of a load. When I removed all images though, it worked smoothly. So choppiness appears only if there are full screen images in sections.

Comment: I uploaded it here, the same choppy loading persists via web as well. http://mnabievart.com/TabletPortfolio_3 (don't mind few graphic glitches due to different screen size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you just posted took 94 seconds to load on my PC using Chrome. And it had plenty of console errors.

Besides that, it is clearly a problem of performance with your site.

You are trying to create a **HUGE** website layout. With **30 sections** and nothing less than **105 slides**...

Do not expect it to work smooth on a mobile phone. Your layout in a 1280x1024 resolution is creating a layout of 28.170 pixels height and a few more thousand pixels width. And all of it has to be moved on every scroll.

You can probably make it easier for your browser if you implement some lazy load technique (or even an ajax one for the section/slide contents). This way you will still having the huge layout but it will be empty at least. 
Check out [this answer](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/46#issuecomment-26509996) for that. 
You can even take a look at the [lazy load](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#lazy-loading) option fullpage.js provides.

Also, using the option `scrollBar:true` might improve the performance.

Comment: Well the whole idea was to use fullpage.js as a platform for the offline app, so loading time is shorter when loading from local storage and those console errors are just missing resources stored separately. I tried both lazyload and scrollBar, it didn't change much. So I came up with solution of adding .section{-webkit-transform : translate3d(0,0,0);} into my css. I doesn't remove choppiness completely, there is still a quick blackish flash when swiping between sections, but it's way less choppy than without it. I guess I will have to manually flash to Android 5.0 to forget about WebView.

Comment: Also consider what I suggested. Adding content dynamically for each section.